# 301 redirect with domain both pointing to same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cpanel

I am currently moving from one domain to another. Both domains are add on domains in CPanel and point to the same sub-directory.

How can i set up 301 redirect that redirects all of the old domains pages to the same file in the new domain. For example olddomain.com/example to newdomain.com/example. Since both domains reside in the same sub directory the both utilize the same .htaccess file.

Since both domains share the same .Htaccess file I'm having trouble getting the 301 redirect to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain.com
RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It will check what your host-header is, and will redirect anything to `newdomain.com` if that's not the current site.